# python regular expression degree sign

Tags: python, regex

I came across the code below and I am wondering what the small circle/degree sign means. The code is supposed to extract text between Item 1A and Item B. Thank you!

```
(?s)(?i)°Item 1A.*?°Item
```

Comment: Isn't it part of the string to match? what is the input string for this regex?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Nothing in the referenced duplicate describes `°`.

Comment: And to answer in a comment, `°` is treated as a literal character. I presume the input language uses it as a bullet marking the items.

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm pretty sure it's part of the string to match itself. I don't see how non-ASCII (32-127) chars would be a part of the special regex chars. I agree it's not a duplicate. but since it's part of the string to match, it's just "unclear" or sth like that.

Comment: It is not part of the [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Thank you all! Sorry, I do not have the string. Your answer makes the perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degree symbol, `°` is treated as a literal character to be matched. Your input probably looks like this:

```
°Item 1A: Giraffes. Girrafes are taller than anteaters.
°Item 1B: Elephants. Elephants are taller than anteaters.
°Item 1C: Ants. Ants are shorter than anteaters.
```

So your regular expression starts its match at `°Item1A` and continues through the first subsequent `°Item`.